# How to use emacs with common music?

Tags: emacs, scheme

For my music purposes  i use [Common music 3.9.0](http://commonmusic.sourceforge.net/#music). Package from sourceforge contains kind of ide but without autocopletion, code folding etc.
So I prefer to use GNU Emacs for live coding.

I found few HOWTO's but it all outdated.

So is it possible to execute Common music processes inside Emacs and how can I do it?

UPD:
On LinuxAudio.org i found some info that may help

> Binary archives of CM contain two fully relocatable applications: bin/Grace is the GUI environment and bin/cm is a console version of the same basic runtime but suitable for using as an inferior scheme process within Emacs.

But in /bin folder only one Grace file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From version 3.9.0 package work only with Grace gui. Best analog working in Emacs is [Extempore project](https://github.com/digego/extempore)